# MicroSD возвращается в исходное состояние

Tags: usb, sd

**Transcend MicroSD HC 32GB class 10**

---

После восстановления файлов c помощью RecoveRx (родная) и еще некоторыми популярными программами (уже не вспомню), что бы я с ней не делал она возвращается в исходное состояние. Файлы, которые остались на ней, я могу смотреть, копировать но не удалять и добавлять.

[youtube](https://youtu.be/y_ki1FxgNKk)

Comment: @approximatenumber Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

На вашем месте я бы отложил в сторону всякие GUI-программы и воспользовался штатными консольными утилитами: `fdisk`, `mkfs`, `mount`, `cp`/`mv`/`rm`... Так проще диагностировать, если есть какие-то неопределенные проблемы. Далее, если на каком-то этапе что-то пошло не так, то вывод сюда.